# Method invocation count Assertion

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock, powermock

I've just started playing with  PowerMock and EasyMock and I'm a bit confused about the way mocked method invocations are counted.

Example code:

```
class ClassToBeTested{
 private boolean toBeMocked(Integer i){
  return i%2==1; 
  }
 }
```

And the test code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassToBeTested.class)
public class ClassToBeTestedTest{

 private final Integer i=2;
 ClassToBeTested underTest;

 @Before
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
  underTest=PowerMock.createPartialMock(ClassToBeTested.class,
                    "toBeMocked");
  PowerMock.expectPrivate(underTest, "toBeMocked", i)
            .andReturn(true);
  PowerMock.replay(underTest);
 }
 @Test
 public dummyTest(){
  Assert.assertTrue(underTest.toBeMocked(i);
  //the call is: underTest.toBeMocked(2)
  //so the computation is return 2%2==1; google says it 0 :)
  //thus real method would return 0==1 (false)
  //mocked one will return true, assertion should pass, that's ok
  //RERUN ASSERTION
  Assert.assertTrue(underTest.toBeMocked(i);
  //method invocation count should be now 2
}

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
   PowerMock.verify(underTest);
   //WILL FAIL with exception saying
   //the mocked method has not been called at all
   //expected value (obvious) is one
}
```

And my question is, why does the mocked method invocation expectation fail?
Why verifying `ClassUnderTest` reveals that mocked method wasn't called at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, after changing the expect line to:

```
 PowerMock.expectPrivate(underTest, "toBeMocked", i).andReturn(true).times(2);
```

Even without that change, it doesn't say the mocked mother wasn't called. It says

```
  Unexpected method call toBeMocked(2):
    toBeMocked(2): expected: 1, actual: 2
```

Are you using the most up to date PowerMock and EasyMock versions?

Comment: **My fault** The example I presented above was made on the baiss of the real problem, but unfortunately I **missed** one important issue that explains my problem:

Comment: **My fault** The example I presented above was made on the baiss of the real problem, but unfortunately I **missed** one important issue that explains my problem: my Test dummyMethod in real example isdivided into two Test methods that run the same mocked method. My expectations is, the mocked method will be run only **once** by all Test methods. I thought **wrongly** than After method will be called **once** after the execution of all Test methods. One Test method doesn't call mocked method at all, so actual call is O, expected 1, thus my question...